# Can I delete a range of events in my Google Calendar without sending notifications?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

> I have been using this code to delete events from a google Calendar

```
var fromDate = new Date(2013,0,1,0,0,0);
var toDate = new Date(2013,0,4,0,0,0);
var calendarName = 'My Calendar';

// delete from Jan 1 to end of Jan 4, 2013

var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++){
  var ev = events[i];
  Logger.log(ev.getTitle()); // show event name in log
  ev.deleteEvent();
}
```

> But if I do a range of events it sends an email to the organiser to say I have declined the event.
>   Can I turn this notification off?

Comment: I realise I can do this by changing the settings for the Calendar, but can I do that with app script?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You can modify the notifications settings, and specifically, disable notifications on cancelled events, through the UI, by selecting **Settings and sharing** and in **Other notifications**, setting `Canceled events` to `None`.

If I understand you correctly, you want to do this programmatically, using Apps Script.

#### Solution:

As far as I know, there is no Apps Script built-in method to manage these settings. Because of this, you should enable [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) and use Calendar API methods.

In Calendar API, notifications are managed by the property `notificationSettings` from the [CalendarList resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#notificationSettings). To change these settings, you have to use the method [CalendarList: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/patch), which you can use to update an existing calendar.

#### Code sample:

```js
function disableNotifications() {
  var calendarId = "your-calendar-id";
  var resource = {
    notificationSettings: {
      notifications: [
        {
          type: "eventCreation",
          method: "email"
        },
        {
          type: "eventChange",
          method: "email"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  Calendar.CalendarList.patch(resource, calendarId);
}
```

#### Note:

- The above sample, for example, would disable all notification types for this Calendar, apart from `eventCreation` and `eventChange`. You can adapt this to your preferences by adding or removing types ([here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#notifications) are the possible types).

#### Reference:

- [Calendar API: Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#notifications)
- [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar)
- [CalendarList: notificationSettings](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#notificationSettings)
- [CalendarList: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/patch)

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and see how I get on.